# Simple JS/jQuery notification system

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to front-end development and now I'm learning JavaScript with jQuery.
I couldn't understand JavaScript's classes and objects and jQuery plugins, but after reading some articles and examples I wrote simple notifications system.

```
(function ($) {
    var notification = function (title, msg, duration) {
        var self = this;

        this.hide = function () {
            self.element.fadeOut(1000, function () {
                self.element.remove();
            })
        }

        this.element = $('<div class="notification"><h3>' + title + '</h3><div class="notification_body">' + msg + '<br/><i>(double click to hide)</i></div></div>');
        this.element.dblclick(self.hide);

        if (duration !== undefined) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                self.hide();
            }, duration * 1000);
        }

        $('#notifications_bar').prepend(this.element.hide().fadeIn(1000));
    };
    $.extend({
        notify:function (title, msg, duration) {
            return new notification(title, msg, duration);
        }
    });
```

Example:

```
$(function() {
    $.notify('Title', 'Message'); // sticky note
    $.notify('Title', 'Message', 2); // 2-seconds notification
});
```

The most terrible were closures and `this` keyword. I couldn't understand how to use them, so I want to know if there in my code above 'bad-practice' parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of, for someone learning jQuery and JavaScript, you've done a great job of avoiding the pitfalls of most new developers to JavaScript;

1. You're not passing strings to `setTimeout`, which a lot of people do.
2. You've got a good grasp on closures (no matter how long they took you to learn :)).
3. You're using strict equals (`===`) rather than equals.

... so, if you want me to be really, *really* picky;

1. I don't see much point in adding your code to the jQuery namespace. It would work just as well to be added to your own namespace. A lot of people fall into the habit of defining *everything* on `$`, and are scared of declaring your own namespace; don;t be:

   ```
   var ME = {};

   ME.notify = function (title, msg, duration) {
       return new notification(title, msg, duration);
   };
   ```
2. It's a code convention to use a capital letter for constructors (e.g. functions you need to call `new` on); change `function notification` to `function Notification`.
3. You could make use of [prototypical inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work). As it stands, you're defining and adding a `hide` function on every instance of a notification you create. Obviously this has a negligible memory impact. Instead, use prototypical inheritance, and declare the function once;

   ```
   function Notification (blah, blah, blah) {
      // blah blah blah
   } 

   Notification.prototype.hide = function () {
       var self = this;

       this.element.fadeOut(1000, function () {
           self.element.remove();
       });
   }
   ```

   ... you'd then have to change your double click handler to use the anonymous function approach I recommended in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15309663/444991), as `this` will no longer be the correct `this`.
4. You've got a potential [XSS exploit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). For example, given the `message`:

   ```
   <script>alert(document.cookie);</script>
   ```

   This will be injected, and evaluated in your page. You can fix this by setting the `h3` and `p` using `text()` explicitly;

   ```
   this.element = $('<div class="notification"><h3></h3><div class="notification_body"><span class="text"></span><br/><i>(double click to hide)</i></div></div>');

   this.element.find('h3').text(title);
   this.element.find('span.text').text(message);
   ```

... but again, I want to re-iterate that I'm being *very*, ***very*** picky. What you've got is well written, functioning JavaScript.

Comment: Awesome answer, big thank you again for taking the time for me. I have some questions about your corrections:
1. In which namespace constructor Notification should be? `Me.Notification` and `Me.notify`?
4. Notification's info receiving from server, so I think I needn't use `text` method, is it correct? Some HTML codes can be used (for example <b>, <i>, etc.)

Comment: @DarkNeo: You can still keep your `Notification` constructor private as you have done, and only expose the `notify` method on your own namespace. Note that the captial `E` (i.e. `ME`) was deliberate for your namespace; I recommend either using all caps (`ME`) or camelCase (`me`) for your namespace, otherwise it could get confused as a Constructor function.

Comment: @DarkNeo: And yes, it was only a possible XSS exploit; providing you're sanitizing the input, you're good to go.

Comment: Okay, Matt, thank you, I made changes in my code as you recommended. Have a nice day :)